# How to make a tkinter gui vertical multiple choice quiz?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

The problem is idk how to make a vertical style multiple choice question quiz asking for the capitals of countries and allowing for a multiple choice to choose the correct country. I currently have made a welcome home frame for asking for the users name and age to enter my quiz and I'm stuck on how to write the code for the next frame. I have attached screenshots below at how I want the multiple choice quiz to be similar to my first frame where the question and multiple choice is underneath the black and white title label named Quiz Question, I want to try and make a second frame containing the multiple choice question that can be accessed from a radio button named next from the first frame code I have shown below.

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk

class CapitalQuiz:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        
        '''Widgets for Welcome Frame'''
        
        self.Welcome = Frame(parent)
        self.Welcome.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        self.TitleLabel = Label(self.Welcome, text = "Welcome to Capital Quiz",
                                bg = "black", fg = "white", width = 20, padx = 30, pady = 10, font = ("Time", '14', "bold italic"))
        self.TitleLabel.grid(columnspan = 2)
        
        #Name and Age Labels
        
        self.NameLabel = Label(self.Welcome, text = "Name", anchor = W,
                               fg = "black", width = 10, padx = 30, pady = 10, font = ("Time", '12', "bold italic"))
        self.NameLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        
        self.AgeLabel = Label(self.Welcome, text = "Age", anchor = W,
                              fg = "black", width = 10, padx = 30, pady = 10, font = ("Time", '12', "bold italic"))
        self.AgeLabel.grid(row=3, column = 0)
        
        #Name and Age Entry
        
        self.NameEntry = ttk.Entry(self.Welcome, width = 20)
        self.NameEntry.grid(row=2, column = 1, columnspan = 2)
        
        self.AgeEntry = ttk.Entry(self.Welcome, width = 20)
        self.AgeEntry.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
        
        #Difficulty level label and radio buttons
        
        self.WarningLabel = Label(self.Welcome, text = "", anchor=W, fg = "red", width = 20, padx = 30, pady = 10)
        self.WarningLabel.grid(row=4, columnspan = 2)
        
        self.DifficultyLabel = Label(self.Welcome, text = "Choose Difficulty level", anchor=W, fg = "black", width = 10, padx = 30, pady = 10, font = ("Time", '12',"bold italic"))
        self.DifficultyLabel.grid(row=5, column = 0)
        
        self.difficulty = ["Easy", "Medium", "Hard"]
        self.diff_lvl = StringVar()
        self.diff_lvl.set(0)
        self.diff_btns = [ ]
        
        for i in range(len(self.difficulty)):
            self.rb = Radiobutton(self.Welcome, variable = self.diff_lvl, value = i, text = self.difficulty[i], anchor = W, padx = 50, width = "5", height = "2")
            self.diff_btns.append(self.rb)
            self.rb.grid(row = i+6, column = 0, sticky = W)
        
        '''Widgets for Question Frame'''
        self.Questions = Frame(parent)
        
        self.QuestionsLabel = Label(self.Questions, text = "Quiz Questions", bg = "black", fg = "white", width = 20, padx = 30, pady = 10,font = ("Time", '14', "bold italic"))
       self.QuestionsLabel.grid(columnspan = 2)
        
        self.HomeButton = ttk.Button(self.Questions, text = 'Home', command = self.show_Welcome)
        self.HomeButton.grid(row = 8, column = 1)
        
        '''A Method that removes Questions Frame'''
        
    def show_Welcome(self):
        self.Questions.grid_remove()
        self.Welcome.grid()
        
    def show_Questions(self):
        
        try:
            if self.NameEntry.get() == "":
                self.WarningLabel.configure(text = "Please enter name")
                self.NameEntry.focus()
                
            elif self.NameEntry.get().issalpha() == False:
                self.WarningLabel.configure(text = "Please enter text")
                self.NameEntry.delete(0, END)
                self.NameEntry.focus()
                
            elif self.AgeEntry.get() == "":
                self.WarningLabel.configure(text = "Please enter age")
                self.AgeEntry.focus()
                
            elif int(self.AgeEntry.get()) > 12:
                self.WarningLabel.configure(text = "You are too old!")
                self.AgeEntry.delete(0, END)
                self.AgeEntry.focus()
                
            elif int(self.AgeEntry.get()) < 0:
                self.WarningLabel.configure(text = "You are too old")
                self.AgeEntry.delete(0, END)
                self.AgeEntry.focus()
            
            elif int(self.AgeEntry.get()) < 7:
                self.WarningLabel.configure(text = "You are too young")
                self.AgeEntry.delete(0, END)
                self.AgeEntry.focus()
                
            else:
                self.Welcome.grid_remove()
                self.Questions.grid()
            
        except ValueError:
            self.WarningLabel.configure(text = "Please enter a number")
            self.AgeEntry.delete(0, END)
            self.AgeEntry.focus()
```

Comment: Please fix the markup around your code.

Comment: could You provide [mre] and what You tried? what specific issue are You facing?

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your code and your requirements for your program CapitalQuiz. I made some changes in code you attach. I change the method of the showing **Titletext** because according to your method you have to create label everytime to show Titletext when you switch the frames between because the TitleLabel is the part of the Welcome frame

> self.TitleLabel = Label(**self.Welcome**, text = "Welcome to Capital
> Quiz",bg = "black", fg = "white", width = 20, padx = 30, pady = 10,
> font = ("Time", '14', "bold italic"))
>
> self.TitleLabel.grid(columnspan = 2)

I remove it from **Welcome** frame & pack it in parent with Welcome frame so now we only have to change the frame to QuestionFrame to swich between. Also i created function called **setTitleLabelText** to set Titlelabel text using textvarible anytime & anywhere.

I wrote the method to switch to Questions Frame and change Title to "Questions". For switch to Questions frame we a need button but you had not created so i create one called Start Quiz in Welcome Frame. I have not write the code to load a question i have only write the code to switch to a questions frame and from questions frame to Welcomr frame.

Here's the code.

```
    from tkinter import*
    from tkinter import ttk
    
    class CapitalQuiz:
        def __init__(self,parent):
            
            '''Title Label. I remove it from welcome frame cause ,
            when we change the frame we have to again create another label to show other title which is make program slow
            I pack it in parent window with welcome frame and asign tkinter StringVar so we can change it anytime 
            from anywhere with function'''
    
            self.Titletext = StringVar()        
            self.TitleLabel = Label(parent, textvariable=self.Titletext,
                                    bg = "black", fg = "white", width = 20, padx = 30, pady = 10, font = ("Time", '14', "bold italic"))
            self.TitleLabel.pack(side="top",fill="x")
            #Function to set TitleLabelText
            self.setTitleLabeltext("Welcome to CapitalQuiz")
    
            #Welcome Frame 
            self.Welcome = Frame(parent)
            self.Welcome.pack(fill="both")
    
            '''Widgets for Welcome Frame'''
            #Name and Age Labels
            
            self.NameLabel = Label(self.Welcome, text = "Name", anchor = W,
                                   fg = "black", width = 10, padx = 30, pady = 10, font = ("Time", '12', "bold italic"))
            self.NameLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
            
            self.AgeLabel = Label(self.Welcome, text = "Age", anchor = W,
                                  fg = "black", width = 10, padx = 30, pady = 10, font = ("Time", '12', "bold italic"))
            self.AgeLabel.grid(row=3, column = 0)
            
            #Name and Age Entry
            
            self.NameEntry = ttk.Entry(self.Welcome, width = 20)
            self.NameEntry.grid(row=2, column = 1, columnspan = 2)
            
            self.AgeEntry = ttk.Entry(self.Welcome, width = 20)
            self.AgeEntry.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
            
            #Difficulty level label and radio buttons
            
            self.WarningLabel = Label(self.Welcome, text = "", anchor=W, fg = "red", width = 20, padx = 30, pady = 10)
            self.WarningLabel.grid(row=4, columnspan = 2)
            
            self.DifficultyLabel = Label(self.Welcome, text = "Choose Difficulty level", anchor=W, fg = "black", width = 10, padx = 30, pady = 10, font = ("Time", '12',"bold italic"))
            self.DifficultyLabel.grid(row=5, column = 0)
            
            self.difficulty = ["Easy", "Medium", "Hard"]
            self.diff_lvl = StringVar()
            self.diff_lvl.set(0)
            self.diff_btns = [ ]
            
            for i in range(len(self.difficulty)):
                self.rb = Radiobutton(self.Welcome, variable = self.diff_lvl, value = i, text = self.difficulty[i], anchor = W, padx = 50, width = "5", height = "2")
                self.diff_btns.append(self.rb)
                self.rb.grid(row = i+6, column = 0, sticky = W)
    
            '''A button to switch to Questions Frame'''
            row = len(self.difficulty)
            self.StartQuizButton = ttk.Button(self.Welcome, text = 'Start Quiz',command=self.show_Questions)
            self.StartQuizButton.grid(row = row+6, column = 0,pady=5,columnspan=3)
    
            '''Widgets for Question Frame'''
            self.Questions = Frame(parent)
            
            self.QuestionsLabel = Label(self.Questions, text = "Quiz Questions", bg = "black", fg = "white", width = 20, padx = 30, pady = 10,font = ("Time", '14', "bold italic"))
            self.QuestionsLabel.pack(fill="both")
            self.QuestionsLabel.pack_forget()
    
            self.HomeButton = ttk.Button(self.Questions, text = 'Home',command=self.showWelcomeFrame)
            self.HomeButton.grid(row = 8, column = 0,columnspan=3)
            
            # '''A Method that removes Questions Frame'''
            
        def setTitleLabeltext(self,text):
            # This method can be use in class multiple times so,
            # we dont have to make individual function everytime to show TitleText
            self.Titletext.set(text)
    
        def showQuestionFrame(self):
            self.Welcome.pack_forget()
            self.Questions.pack(fill="both")#Here we have to specify the pack values again becuase we called pack_forget befor
            self.setTitleLabeltext("Questions")
    
        def showWelcomeFrame(self):
            self.Questions.pack_forget()
            self.Welcome.pack(fill="both")#Here we have to specify the pack values again becuase we called pack_forget before
            self.setTitleLabeltext("Welcome to CapitalQuiz")
            self.NameEntry.delete(0,"end")
            self.AgeEntry.delete(0,"end")
    
        def show_Questions(self):
            
            try:
                if self.NameEntry.get() == "":
                    self.WarningLabel.configure(text = "Please enter name")
                    self.NameEntry.focus()
                    
                elif self.NameEntry.get().isalpha() == False:
                    self.WarningLabel.configure(text = "Please enter text")
                    self.NameEntry.delete(0, END)
                    self.NameEntry.focus()
                    
                elif self.AgeEntry.get() == "":
                    self.WarningLabel.configure(text = "Please enter age")
                    self.AgeEntry.focus()
                    
                elif int(self.AgeEntry.get()) > 12:
                    self.WarningLabel.configure(text = "You are too old!")
                    self.AgeEntry.delete(0, END)
                    self.AgeEntry.focus()
                    
                elif int(self.AgeEntry.get())
```